# converting Object [] to double [] in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, double

Is this possible? I have been struggling with this for a while. I was originally casting to `Long []` first and then converting to `double []` which let me compile but then gave me an error for the casting. I am now stuck.

In this code, I am iterating over the entries in my hashmap.

```
 Object[] v = null;
 for(Map.Entry<String,NumberHolder> entry : entries)
 {
       v = entry.getValue().singleValues.toArray(); //need to get this into double []
 }
```

Here is my numberHolder class

```
private static class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurrences = 0;
    public ArrayList<Long> singleValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

Comment: why does v need to be an array of objects?

Comment: I would make singleValues a `TDoubleArrayList` which allows you to call toArray() to return a `double[]`  Note: a `double[]` is not an `Object[]` as a `double` is not an `Object`

Comment: @BenGreen it doesn't I was just going to take that and attempt to get it to double []

Comment: Be careful with any conversion of `long -> double` cause there is a loss of precision. So if you're working with highly precise numbers you could get issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-generic `toArray` might not be optimal, I'd recommend you to use a `for` loop instead:

```
Long[] v = new Long[entry.getValue().singleValues.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Long v : entry.getValue().singleValues) {
  v[i++] = v;
}
```

Now you've got an *array of `Long` objects* instead of `Object`. However, `Long` is an integral value rather than floating-point. You should be able to cast, but it smells like an underlying problem.

You can also **convert directly** instead of using a `Long` array:

```
double[] v = new double[entry.getValue().singleValues.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Long v : entry.getValue().singleValues) {
  v[i++] = v.doubleValue();
}
```

**Concept:** you must not try to convert *the array* here, but instead *convert each element* and store the results in a *new array*.

Comment: Or just `v.doubleValue()`, since Long instanceof Number.

Answer (score 2):

In order to "convert" an array of type `Object[]` to `double[]` you need to create a new `double[]` and populate it with values of type `double`, which you'll get by casting each `Object` from the input array separately, presumably in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This smells a bit as some bad practice.
First of all, I discourage you to use arrays, use Map or List.

If you need the values as double, make a getter which

```
private List<Long> myList;
//initialize somewhere

double getElementAsDouble(int index){
    return myList.get(index).doubleValue();
}
```

And add a converter like getMyListAsDoubleArray() where you make the conversion if you really have to use Array. You can check out the solution from the answers here, for example Matthias Meid's.

Comment: I have to use the array because I am making a graph and the method `dataset.addSeries` only accepts `double []`

Comment: @user2007843 I see, I still recommend to make a converter instead of doing the job locally.